# Primefaces Picklist problem

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am having a text field in my xhtml whose property i have set to required="true" and then i have primefaces picklist.

Now when validations fails like mandatory "textbox" is not filled. I throws an error and my page picklist becomes corrupted (all alignment) and if i see in generated html there will be no imports for primefaces like imports for picklist css and js.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answere for the problem myself.
It was actually bcoz of a very silly problem.
One needs to do **"render={SomeId of form element}"** in the CommandButton.
All the things will work fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Put in your tag picklist required attribute, like this:

<p:pickList id="pickListProfile" value="#{bean.profile}" var="profile"                                  itemLabel="#{profile.description}" itemValue="#{profile}"                                   converter="profilePickListConverter" responsive="true" **required="true"**>

It works for me.

Comment: What is you don't want the pickList to be required?

Comment: Hi @JasperdeVries, the problem case is: 1. You have a picklist in your form. 2. In your form there are other components in required. 3. After you submit form and validation fails, Picklist won't work.